# Magento: Cannot Add products To Cart With Configurable Products

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Yes, I've looked at all of the answers and none of them seem to be problems I'm facing. On my site when I'm on the product details page with a configurable product. It doesn't even let me select my option. I sell vaporizers and I need different color options and Magento or my theme isn't letting me do this. It simply now is acting a "Add To Cart" image with absolute no value or function. Doesn't let me add anything to the cart using configurable products.

If you know a solution, don't just write a silly code. specify the file and directory. I'm no programmer.

Here is the direct url to the page with configurable product.

```
    http://yourvaporizers.com/index.php/vaporizers/pen/atmos-bullet.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its your css problem.
The position of the description tabs is relative so you cannot select it.
Make this changes `.col-main .ui-tabs {position: inherit;padding:0}` in `/skin/frontend/exdress/default/css/styles.css`

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you so much, you've saved lots of time. I know a little CSS and you forgot to end the code with the closing tag ";" . No biggie I just switched relative to inherit and now it works.  Can I ask what tool you used to find it out? Fiddler?

Comment: No i also faced this error. So i just went to your site and checked wheather its the same error or not. You are Most Welcome!!

Comment: And it is ok if we do not add ";" to the last attribute before "}".It still works.

Comment: Yea,  very nice, thanks little lady. Very pretty for someone in this field if that's u.